# What's happening in this line?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I created a form  named "questionario" with checkboxes, and made an IF statement to send a msgbox if all the cheboxes were blank. But when I run the macro an error (error 438) occur in the quoted line.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ind As Integer
Dim cont As MSForms.Control
ind = 0

If questionario.resp1.Value = True Then
Range("E8").Value = Range("E8").Value + 1
End If
If questionario.resp2.Value = True Then
Range("F8").Value = Range("F8").Value + 1
End If
If questionario.resp3.Value = True Then
Range("G8").Value = Range("G8").Value + 1
End If


For Each cont In questionario.Controls
```

> If (TypeName(cont) = "CheckBox") And (cont.Value = True) Then

```
ind = ind + 1

End If
Next


If ind = 0 Then
MsgBox "mmm"
Else
questionario.Hide
Set questionario = Nothing
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you try doing `If cont.TypeName = ... `?

Comment: I tried, but I think the problem is with the `And (cont.Value = True)` part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

divide your check into two steps:

```
For Each cont In questionario.Controls
    If TypeName(cont) = "CheckBox" Then
        If cont.Value Then '<-- a checkbox control has a Value property
            ind = ind + 1
            Exit For '<-- no need to go on
        End If
    End If
Next
```

The reason for this is that some control types do not have a `.Value` property, and VBA does not short-circuit boolean expressions. So, even if the `cont.TypeName` <> "CheckBox", the expression still attempts to query the `.Value` property of those controls which may not have such a propery.

Comment: I won't add as an answer, as this answer does the trick.  A label for instance, doesn't have a `Value` property so will throw an error.  Edit:  and user3598756 has addressed that now. :)

Comment: It worked, thanks! Do you know why it doesn't work when I don't divide into two steps?

Comment: Thanks @DarrenBartrup-Cook

Comment: you are welcome. It's because of what I put in the comment (perhaps too much concise) and @DarrenBartrup-Cook cleared in more detail: not all userform controls have a `Value` property while `If (TypeName(cont) = "CheckBox") And (cont.Value = True) Then` statement would check both conditions to return its result, thus trying to access `Value` property of a `Control` even if the `TypeName(cont) = "CheckBox"` part would return `False`